# Understanding Database connection java eclipse & db2

Tags: database, eclipse, db2

Can someone help me understand these two more better?

1. "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"

   - Is this a default?
   - Where can I find this path? Do I just copy and paste it?
2. "jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/dbname","username","password"

   - Is this a default?
   - How would I find out my userId and Password?

Answer (score 0):

There are several driver types.

http://razorsql.com/docs/help_db2.html

Yours is jdbc4 version, last java-jdbc driver, maybe your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read this example of a [Simple JDBC Application using Java](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvjdbas.html).

In short:

- **com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver** is JDBC driver class
- You need to provide **{username}** and **{password}** in order to connect to database. You can get from database administrator or you should know if you installed your database.

Comment: Thank you! I was playing with my codes and still wasn't able to run it appropriately until now. I never thought that I still need to download the JDBC and add that as an external jar to my project.